# How to "OCR" pictures of my electric meter?

Tags: ocr

Below is a picture of my electric meter reading 52425.5 (roughly):

[image]

What program/technique will help me read the meter automatically? Notes:

- This is one of the cleaner images. Many images have static. I'm OK 
  w/ ignoring (having the program say "ERR") pictures w/ too much static.
- The camera has a fixed mount, but the middle of each dial (the 
  bright silver points) move up and down between pictures (because of 
  differing vertical sync?). The dial centers (thus the entire picture) 
  also moves a little left and right between pictures, but not as 
  much.
- More pictures and some code: 
  https://github.com/barrycarter/bcapps/tree/master/ELECREAD
- My approach so far:

  - Break the picture into individual dials.
  - Find the center of each dial (ie, the "brightest point")
  - Look at circles with different radii around the center and find 
    the darkest angle for each circle.
  - Do something (not sure what yet) with the darkest angles you 
    find to get a reading.
- I'm aware there are devices which watch your meter and 
  record/broadcast how many "cycles" they've seen (each cycle = 7.5 
  watt-hours on most meters). However, these devices are expensive, and 
  can't "catch up" if they miss a few readings.

Any thoughts?

UPDATE: it's FAR from perfect, but https://github.com/barrycarter/bcapps/blob/master/ELECREAD/bc-elec-read.pl now correctly reads 6 of the 100 test images, incorrectly reads 8 of the 100 test images, and rejects the other 86 test images (including the one below) as being "unreadable". In actual practice (and when knowing previous reliable readings), it does quite a bit better.

Comment: I have been working with OCR solutions for more than 10 years and I can tell you that this images are in very bad quality. You will never get reliable results from them even when using professional solutions. I can give you a link to product that I use for OCR. Take a look it might get you handy, but consider getting better images first: http://www.gp-solutions.si/business/NewsItem.aspx?id=4

Comment: I agree the images are poor quality. Luckily, I don't need to read the numbers on the meter, because the camera is in fixed position (if you rotate the image about 5 degrees to the left, the center dots will all line up). I just need the position of the center and the angle of the "pointer" for each dial, which I think might be more do-able.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have a look at opencv

> OpenCV (Open Source Computer Vision) is a library of programming functions for real time computer vision.

http://opencv.org/

http://opencv.willowgarage.com/wiki/